# Bootstrap CSS - How do I keep the search form inline with other navbar elements?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

New to CSS, I'm trying to keep my search form in-line with the other navbar elements, and weird thing is when initially going to the page it's on 2 lines, yet when I refresh it's in-line. How do I keep this in-line?

[image]

```
<div class="blog-masthead">
<div class="container">        
        <nav class="blog-nav">
            <a class="blog-nav-item" href="{{ path('general_sym_project_homepage') }}">Home</a>
            <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">New features</a>
            <a class="blog-nav-item" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
            <a class="blog-nav-item" href="http://www.symfony.com">Resources</a>
            <a class="blog-nav-item" href="{{ path('general_sym_project_about') }}">About</a>

            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>

        </nav>
 </div>
 </div>

.blog-nav-item {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
font-weight: 500;
color: #cdddeb;
}
.blog-nav-item:hover,
.blog-nav-item:focus {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Active state gets a caret at the bottom */
.blog-nav .active {
color: #fff;
}
.blog-nav .active:after {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 50%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
margin-left: -5px;
vertical-align: middle;
content: " ";
border-right:  5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 5px solid;
border-left:   5px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a rule for **navbar-right**. Just add these css;

```
.navbar-right{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work when I initially go to the page it still displays on 2 lines. Not sure why it's not working every time yet works when I reload the page.

Comment: Is it a problem with using masthead and a search form?

Comment: Maybe or not. If the problem still exist, you can add your form another nav. I can try it for you. Could you share jsfiddle link?

Comment: Figured out the solution from davidpauljunior - by using <ul></ul> and <li> worked perfectly everytime.